# Bookshelf ORM, get the latest record with find query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm

using bookshelf orm, while making find one query.. getting first record only.

```
 userDetails
        .findOne({ user_id: user.attributes.id }, { require: false })
```

Is there any sort kind of things, to get the latest created record from table.

Comment: Bookshelf doesn't have a `findOne` method according to [doc](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html), neither does [knex](http://knexjs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15). How is `userDetails` declared ?

Comment: yes it has, check with bookshelf-modelbase, I have made internal configuration.

Comment: Ok since it extends bookshelf model, you can use `orderBy` and `where` functions

Answer (score 2):

In the `bookshelf-modelbase` plugin there is no method `orderBy` and you can't chain the [bookshelf's `orderBy`](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-orderBy) method with `bookshelf-modelbase`'s `findOne`.

So there is a way to do it using bookshelf's methods:

```js
userDetails
  .where({ user_id: user.attributes.id })
  .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC') // Last created first
  .fetch({ require: false })
  .then(res => console.log(res.toJSON()))
```